# Accessing <g> in an SVG using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to create a project using this svg file: https://simplemaps.com/custom/us. I'm only able to display the svg if I use an Img tag, but I can't seem to find a way to access the groups in the svg so I can use a hover affect for each group. Is there a way to use an svg in JSX? or will I need to import some library in order to access the groups? I'm also trying to do this project without using Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for to do isn't possible, at least that way.

What you are seeing in the webpage may be an SVG, but the logic of interacting with it is controlled by a `JavaScript` script, not by the SVG.

Even if you manage to get the SVG file from the page, it would only be a mere snapshot of the state it was when you grabbed it.

As an alternative, here are some projects you can look into for your use case:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-map
- https://github.com/salocreative/react-interactive-map